# Is there a word that encompasses both "definitions" and "theorems"?

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing, terminology, article-writing

I sometimes write sentences like this:

> To prove the desired result, the following **notions** will be handy.

What follows is a usually a sequence of definitions, theorems and proofs. Therefore, I don't think that the word 'notions' really fits, because 'theorems' aren't really 'notions' to my mind.

> **Question.** Is there a word that does fit, which encompasses both definitions and theorems?

Comment: For the purpose in question 'statement' might work.

Comment: I also write this often, and wonder if there is something better.

Comment: This isn't an answer so much as a practical suggestion: you don't need a word there. "The following will be handy".

Comment: can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @Arjang

In this part we deal with certain notions from the field of commutative algebra. Certain notions are absolutely necessary to work efficiently with the concepts of algebraic geometry, homological algebra and representation theory.

Comment: @Arjang, I'm tempted to give the example I'm currently looking at, but I'd rather keep it confidential. Perhaps I'll give an example the next time I encounter one.

Comment: I actually see no problem with "the following definitions and theorems will be handy". Alternatively, "tools" could be loosely interpreted to cover both. Aside: As for cranks, are you aware of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/35198) [recurring](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/12574) [case](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/13055) and [this recent case](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27744/why-are-my-answers-being-quietly-deleted/27747#27747)? I don't care if they don't try to mislead students.

Answer (score 1):

"Theory" is theoretically the answer :)
Otherwise,  settings/framework?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to say "facts" or "known facts".

A fact might be known because it comes from a definition, or because it comes from a theorem. But, either way, it is "known", and it's a "fact".

Alternatively, you could just refer to definitions and theorems, as in "to prove the following result, we will use the definition given in section (3.5), plus theorems (3.8) and (3.9)".

Or, more briefly: "to prove the following result, we will use (3.5), (3.8), and (3.9)".

Comment: I must protest, a definition is fundamentally not a fact.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, I tend to agree. A definition *induces* a fact: the definition "$a \mid b$ means there is $b'$ with $b = ab'$" induces the fact that for all integers $a$ and $b$, the statement $a \mid b$ is equivalent to the existence of $b'$ with $b = ab'$. But it feels a bit strange to say that the definition *is* a fact, given that before this definition was introduced, the relevant statement was not even true, because the relevant terms hadn't been introduced.

Comment: I said a fact "comes from" a definition. I didn't say that a fact "is" a definition.  I see your point, but I think that in a discursive pre-amble to a proof, readability is more important than 100% precision. Also, it depends on the topic, presumably. Mathematical logic folks and numerical analysts might have different views, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a slight variation of your sentence:

> To prove the desired result, the following notions and facts will be handy.

Not a single word, but short enough.